# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.getJunitOptions()Ljava/util/List;

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

I am trying to run a simple cucumber feature test. 
Below is my junit runner file &POM.xml file. 
When I try to run feature file individually, it runs and doesn't throw error. But when run using runner file, i get the below mentioned error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.getJunitOptions()Ljava/util/List;

    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
```

I am using same version dependencies:
cucumber-junit
cucumber-jvm
1.2.5

Runner file

```
  package runner;


import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/java/Featurefile/"},
        glue = {"Steps"},
        monochrome = true,
        tags = {},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json",
                "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter: target/report.html"}

)

public class MainRunner {
}
```

POM File

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Extent Reports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.26-incubating</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Can you please suggest where I am making mistake on configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while running cucumber in junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559259/error-while-running-cucumber-in-junit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix for your `pom.xml` would be to change the version number from `1.2.4` to `1.2.5`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The version should be in sync for your dependencies

```
info.cukes:cucumber-jvm:pom:1.2.5:compile
info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.5:test
info.cukes:cucumber-core:jar:1.2.5:test
info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.2.5:test
info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:jar:1.2.5:compile
info.cukes:cucumber-testng:jar:1.2.5:compile
```

It's worth to define a property for it

```
<properties>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version>
</properties>
```

and use it for all related dependencies like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You might also check to use a more recent Cucumber version (the group id has changed and is now `io.cucumber`).

**edit**: The dependency `cucumber-core` and `cucumber-java` are defined twice. Remove the ones at the end of your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Cool. It works now, cucumber-core & java was defined twice in pom file.